# Plot graph using the last 10 values in MS Excel

Tags: excel, plot, graph

So I got Sheet1 with a table containing some data. To simplify let's say there's a column 'x' with some data and a column 'y' with some data. Every now and then more values are manually added to the table.

On Sheet2 I need Excel to automatically plot a graph only using the last 10 values in the table. So when more values are added the graph changes automatically to the new last 10 values. Is this possible?

Furthermore, let's say there's a third column 'z' that's always a constant value (for example to show some kind of a maximum for 'y' in the graph). How to make Excel automatically fill the cell with the number when the according 'x' and 'y' cells are filled? I know I could manually fill the 'z' column all the way down but I suspect that would screw up with plotting the last 10 values.

I'm using MS Excel 2013.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Do you have some sample data you could post?  What have you tried so far to accomplish this? Are you very new to Excel?  I ask since the 2nd part of your question "fill cell Z based on values of cells X and Y" is pretty basic stuff -- with some idea of your comfort level with Excel, charts &  VBA, we might be able to point you to the right place.  (This isn't a "free code writing service" as much as a place for people who want to find & share resources to help us all learn.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a chart using dynamic named ranges as the series data.

Start by setting up the data table with headings x, y and z.

Select x heading and click Insert > Table, make sure "My table has headers" 
is checked then click OK

In column z, to set 20 as the autofilled value, add formula `=20`

Put your data in columns x and y

Create your chart based on columns x and y. This example creates a XY Plot.

Assuming you've only got one table in your workbook, it will be named "Table1".

Go to Formulas > Name Manager > New

xPlot: `=OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[x]],COUNTA(Table1[z])-9,0,10,1)`

Also create:

yPlot: `=OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[y]],COUNTA(Table1[z])-9,0,10,1)`

Right click on your chart and click Select Data...

Remove the Series that is there

Create a new Series

If your workbook was called Chart Example.xlsx, then set:

Series X values: 'Chart Example.xlsx'!xPlot

Series Y values: 'Chart Example.xlsx'!yPlot

Click OK and try adding more data.

[image: Img]

Comment: Michael, thank you for your detailed answer, however, when I try to create a new formula I get "The formula you typed contains an error". I made sure that I followed your guide without any changes to see if it works but I just can't get it to work. I see you have it in your name manager which is strange. I am pretty sure the formula I'm entering is the same, I also double checked it against the screenshot. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't tell without seeing it. There's a few things that could go wrong. Start by checking the table name, click on the Table, then go to the Table tab on the ribbon and check the Table Name on the far left, it needs to be "Table1" for the formulas to work. Also, rather than manually typing the entire formula, you could select the relevant parts with the mouse. The first part needs to be just the header of the column to be plotted, the second part needs to be the entire column with the formula _except_ for the header.

Comment: Ok, with help of a few videos I actually learned what each of those functions do and managed to make it work as I wished. Thank you very much! Without you I wouldn't even know which functions to search for.

The problem with your formula was on my side because my language version of Excel uses ; instead of ,

Comment: You're welcome. Good job doing the research to understand the components to be able to modify as required.